# If data tag equals 1 hide link

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm messing around a bit with `chrome extensions` and am trying to clean up webpages I use a lot. I'm trying to remove certain parts of a list and can see that they are positioned using `html data tags`.

```
<a class"Somelist" href"..." data-tid="1">1st</a>
<a class"Somelist" href"..." data-tid="2">2nd</a>
<a class"Somelist" href"..." data-tid="3">3rd</a>
```

How could I use `jQuery` to hide the link if the link equals 1?

I was trying to use something like

```
`if ( $('.Somelist').data("tid") == 1 ) { // hide }`
```

which obviously does not work. Does anyone know a way that would work? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select by using an [attribute selector (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
$('a[data-tid="1"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do something like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.Somelist').each(function(i,el) {
    if ($(el).data("tid") == 1) {
      alert($(el).data("tid"));
      $(el).hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="Somelist" href "..." data-tid="1">1st</a>
<a class="Somelist" href "..." data-tid="2">2nd</a>
<a class="Somelist" href "..." data-tid="3">3rd</a>
```

The explanation now :

When you use `$('Somelist')` it return an array with all elements corresponding to this selector

[image]

Comment: This works, but will inevitably end up in a bottleneck on a page with a lot of selected elements.

Comment: as ChristopheMarois says you can use jquery selector :`$('a[data-tid="1"]').hide();`